# How to create image list to correspond cell?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

[image]

i have a table view and it contains an add button on navigation bar,click the button will show the add text page,i have already saved the text into the coredata and it will show on the tableview.

then,click the added tableviewcell will show the photo list page ,click the take photo button will add images into the photo list.

i have created one entities that save the text,but i don't know where to save the images,because the save process is not at the same time , and i have to use 'list.count' to show the saved text on tableview.should i create a another entities to save the images?if so ,how can i save the photo list to correspond cell with coredata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entity that stores your text should also have a to-many relationship to a photo entity.  I assume the photo entity would just hold a relative path string (relative to some directory in your app such as the Documents directory).

Your photo list view controller could just be given the managedObject representing the named photos list during prepareForSegue so that it can access the list of image paths and add to the list.

Advanced tip: It'd actually be cleanest to abstract your model classes from CoreData by using protocols, and to use an ID such as a guid assigned to each named photos list entity.  Then pass that ID between your view controllers, along with a reference to your model as a protocol (aka dependency injection).

Comment: thanks for answer my question,i have already saved the photo into the coredata,but it just show on the photo list view controller.because i don't know how to set the relationship between text list controller and photo controller ,so click the tableviewcell  always show the same photo list.i have read the advanced tip,but i can't get the point,perhaps i'm still a newbie.what should i need to learn to solve this problem or what keywords i need to search?

Comment: Does your first viewController have a prepareForSegue method?  It needs one.

Comment: you mean i need to use this method to connect the photo controller to certain cell?

Comment: No. It'd be best if you could add code to your question and explain better what viewControllers you have and what model classes, so I can see the relationships you have so far.

Comment: Actually, if by cell you mean the *text* list cell, then yes, that's exactly what you need to do.